# MVC controller manipulates the JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Here is my code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [Route("whatever")]
        public ActionResult<JsonResult> Get()
        {
            string jsonText = "{\"city\":\"paris\"}";

            return new JsonResult(JObject.Parse(jsonText));
        }
```

This is the output I want:

```
{"city":"paris"}
```

This is the output I get:

```
{"contentType":null,"serializerSettings":null,"statusCode":null,"value":{"city":"paris"}}
```

How can I change my code to prevent .NET framework from wrapping my original JSON?

Comment: Use Ok(your json object) instead of JsonResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then use a simpler and strongly typed result object instead of trying to manually create the JSON string.

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("whatever")]
public IActionResult Get() {
    var model = new { city = "paris" };
    return Ok(model);
}
```

the framework will serialize the model to the desired output

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with ASP.NET MVC's `JsonResult`, but you're using JSON.NET. In JSON.NET, when you convert an json string vi `JObject.Parse()`, it returns a `JObject` object that contains some members. If you want to get the converted json, you should use `ToString()`, as the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("whatever")]
public ActionResult<JsonResult> Get()
{
    string jsonText = "{\"city\":\"paris\"}";
    return new JsonResult(JObject.Parse(jsonText).ToString());
}
```